# Stopping Mocha test suite's execution after a configurable number of test failures

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I want to stop my test suite after a configurable number of tests fails.
My test suite has different files containing Mocha tests.

I want to take input from user in order to know after how many test case failures do they want to stop execution of the complete test suite.
So if the users gives 5 as an input, my test suite should stop after the 5th test cases fail.

Can anyone help me if figuring out how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt:

```
// mocha-plugin-fail-after.js
const { Runner } = require('mocha');
const fail       = Runner.prototype.fail;
const opts       = require('minimist')(process.argv);
const failAfter  = Number(opts['fail-after'] || 5);

let failures = 0;
Runner.prototype.fail = function() {
  if (++failures > failAfter) {
    console.log('\nToo many failures, exiting...');
    process.exit(failures);
  }
  return fail.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

To use:

```
mocha -r mocha-plugin-fail-after --fail-after=5 test/**/*.js
```

Comment: Hi @robertklep,
My Mocha test suite is already using 2 reporters. So should I make a separate npm module for the above and then include it in my test suite as a third party reporter?

Comment: @vedantshete this isn't a reporter, just a plugin (reporters are loaded with `-R`, this one with `-r/--require`)

Comment: the Runner.prototype.fail function is not getting called.

I am using the above plugin. The plugin is getting called but the fail function isn't when I run mocha using -r. 

Hence, all the tests are running and ignoring the Runner.prototype.fail. 
I am not able to understand what modification should I make?

Comment: Which version of Mocha are you using?

Comment: I am using Mocha 4.0.0

Comment: That's what I tested it with. Can you test with this test file? https://gist.github.com/robertklep/6e3d6920e9cab7641d869bfdb4fd5344 (set `fail-after` to 3, for instance)

Comment: thank you for helping me. 
I tried the above test code but again I am facing the same problem. The plugin is getting called(checked with a console.log()) but the fail function is not getting called. The control never goes to Runner.prototype.fail function neither in mocha-plugin-fail-after.js nor in runner.js(the existing prototype fail function). Any further suggestions?

Comment: @vedantshete sorry, I have no idea why it's not working for you while it is for me. Hopefully someone else can either confirm or deny it's working, so we know where to look closer.